# counter button and new button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create button that when clicked it returns how many times it has been clicked as well as every time you Click the button;

a new button is added to the page(It's a new button so it hasn't been clicked yet) Each button added to the page should have the same interaction as the first button. Clicking it increments it's value and create's new button on the page.

So far I got the counter button figured out but can't seem to get to add the button on the page. Please help...

```
var clicks = 0;
function onClick(){
    clicks +=1;
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML=  "I've been clicked " +clicks + 
" times" ;
};
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a9efyju7/2/

Comment: I've forgotten to mention the last part too...And when checking work, make sure that after n button clicks on the page, the sum of all the buttons counters should be n, and there should be n+ 1 button on the page.

Comment: I think that is happening in the above sample

Comment: @ArunPJohny why not answer?

Answer (score 0):

The createElement() method will probably be the easiest way to go... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

```
var clicks = 0;
var button = 0;
function onClick(){
    clicks +=1;
    button++
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML=  "I've been clicked " +clicks + 
" times" ;
    var newButton = document.createElement("button"+button);
    document.body.appendChild(newButton);
    document.getElementById("button"+button).innerHTML = "I Have Not Been Clicked Yet"
};
```

Comment: Never trust w3schools; it's full of errors. And you should provide code examples instead of links.

Comment: I meant to click comment not answer... so I apologize for that. However, for something so simple it hardly matters where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Here`s my code! Hope it helps you...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'es'>
    <head>
        <title> MY TEST </title>
        <meta charset = 'utf-8'>

    </head>
    <body id = 'body'>
        <input type = 'button' value = 'Clicked 0 times' id = 'Button' data-clicks = 0 ></input>

        <script>
            var firstButton = document.getElementById('Button');
            firstButton.addEventListener('click', createAndAdd);

            function createAndAdd(e){
                var button = e.target;

                // Reference to the data-clicks attribute
                var clicksAttribute = button.getAttribute('data-clicks');

                var clicksAttributeValue = parseInt(clicksAttribute);           
                button.value = 'Clicked ' + (clicksAttributeValue + 1) + ' times';

                clicksAttribute = clicksAttributeValue + 1;
                button.setAttribute('data-clicks', clicksAttribute);

                //Creating and adding the attributes of the new button.
                newInputButton = document.createElement('input');
                newInputButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                newInputButton.setAttribute('value', 'Clicked 0 times');
                newInputButton.setAttribute('id', 'Button');
                newInputButton.setAttribute('data-clicks', 0);

                //Adding the event Listener to the new button
                newInputButton.addEventListener('click', createAndAdd)

                //Adding the new button to the body
                var body = document.getElementById('body');
                body.appendChild(newInputButton);

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```